# Error while setting language in RTF field

Tags: 2009

We have the possibility to set the language of a word in a RTF field.
For example, if in our RTF field we have

```
A mere century ago
```

By clicking on the "set language" icon on the top of the Component, the source will automatically update to:

```
A mere <span lang="ar-YE" auto-ns1:lang="ar-YE" xmlns:auto-ns1="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">century</span> ago
```

The problem I have is: when I try to update the source of the RTF field just by adding a random character like a "." then saving and closing the Component, I have the following error:

> ConvertHTML: converted source is not valid XHTML. Namespace
>   "xmlns:xml" is reserved and can only be set as
>   http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace

In order to close the Component, I need to remove the span from the source manually.

What is weird is, if I only use the definition tab (in the RTF field) and not the source tab. The error does not appear.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue on one of our 2009 systems, but do you know that this version is end-of-life? I seriously would consider upgrading to a supported version if I were you.

Comment: I agree with you but it unfortunately does not depend on me...
By the way , i think i found the problem. When i update to false the drop-proprietary-attributes line in my tcmXHTML.config, the problem disappear....